# Conditional formatting in libre office calc

Tags: openoffice-calc

I am trying to achieve the following:

For each columns RN, RO and RP, color the background of the cell in red  if it is less than the number in the RR column on the same row, and in green if it is greater.

[image]

Ideally it would be great to know as well how to easily extend the conditional formatting to additional columns.

Comment: Thanks for providing an image iso. some data to work with.

Comment: is there a way to paste a table ? how would i share data ?. Sample can also be made with much simpler table, just 2 rows and 2 columns, to explain the formatting in green and red

Comment: One possibility would be to export a range as csv, post it here or on a drop site, then someone wanting to help you could import it into Calc and test his/her solution.  Certainly it would make it easier for lazy people like me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of "[conditional formatting based of column / cell value](https://superuser.com/q/1355628/7542)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new cel format profile, with a red background, call it redbg.

Select your range column RN3..RP999, then Format -> Conditional -> Formula.

The formula is $RN3 < $RP3. the format profile is redbg.

Detailed steps as provided by [Outis](https://superuser.com/users/7542/outis) :

1. Create new cell formats, one with a red background and the other with green, and name them appropriately (e.g. "Below Index" and "Above Index"):

   1. Open the "Styles" → "Manage Styles" menu item.
   2. Select the parent style in the style tree (e.g. "Default Cell Style" or "Status").
   3. Click the  green "+" button in the style manager to add a new style. Alternatively, context-click on the parent style and click "New…" on the context menu.
   4. Name the style, then click the "OK" button. Note: this adds the style to the style manager; afterwards, you can drag the style to change its parent.
   5. Context-click the new style and click "Modify…" on the context menu.
   6. Make any desired changes to the style. In this case, go to the "Background" tab and choose the color.
   7. Click the "OK" button when done.
   8. Repeat steps 3–7 to add additional styles.
   9. Close the "Styles and Formatting" panel when done.
2. Select the columns to format
3. Open the "Format" → "Conditional" → "Condition…" menu item.

   1. Condition 1 should already be present. Set the dropdowns to "Cell value" "is less than" and enter "RR2" (or whichever cell in the RR column is the least row) for the condition value.
   2. Set "Apply style" to the appropriate style (e.g. "Below Index").
   3. Beneath the condition list, click the "Add" button.
   4. For condition 2, set the dropdowns to "Cell value" "is greater than" and the value to "RR2" (or whichever cell in the RR column is the least row).
   5. Set "Apply style" to the appropriate style (e.g. "Above Index").
   6. Note you can edit the cell range here, if necessary.
   7. Click the "OK" button