# Libre office, automatically color cell based on value

Tags: conditional-formatting, libreoffice-calc, cell-format

I’m trying to make a planning grid with various tasks and I would like a task to be colorized to easily spot it anywhere else. Each different task should get a different colour.

I can’t find a way to do it using conditional formatting. I would have thought it would be out of the box, but either it’s not or I’m missing something.

Another idea was to create a quick index column with all tasks and manually format that one so that the planning area would retrieve those colour, but cannot get that to work either.

What I really want to avoid is to have to create a conditional format rules for each task since it become cumbersome and task tend to change and evolve.

Here is an example of the expected result (did it manually):

[image]

Comment: *or I’m missing something* - most likely, it is: [**a lot has been written about conditional formatting**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/tag/conditional-format) in Calc, it is difficult to find [**exactly your topic**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/calc-conditional-formatting-based-on-month-value-from-date/24029/3).
This problem has been solved many times - it seems to me that [**this discussion**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/is-there-a-way-to-autohighlight-unique-values-in-a-list-with-unique-colors/82198) is closest to what you are asking about.

Comment: As you mention, searching that topic is quite hard, Always found random things about conditional formatting. I'll look into that last discussion, seems promising, although way more complex than hoped, as the op of the thread pointed out! Thanks for the pointer

Comment: To write there are already answers is a good thing, but if the answers linked are not in StackExchange, you're not right because all answers out of StackExchange are irrelevants beacause they can gone, these sort of link  are only to illustrate.

Comment: one of from "Related" StackEchange answer : https://superuser.com/questions/1355628/libreoffice-calc-conditional-formatting-based-of-column-cell-value/1355900#1355900